# Parse.com Cloud Code beforeSave( ) Error: "Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object"

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, before-save

In ACL of an object 'Hotel' i am trying to save id of 'Parse.User' object. I am saving ACL in beforeSave(). While saving object it gives me an error as **"Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object"**
Which i am unable to resolve.

**Assign User function:**

```
exports.assignUser = function(params) {
    if(!params || !params.userId || !params.id) {
        console.log(Response.ParametersEmpty);
        params.error(Response.EmptyParameters);
    } else {
        var Hotel = Parse.Object.extend('Hotel');
        var dsQuery = new Parse.Query(Hotel);
        dsQuery.equalTo('objectId', params.id);
        dsQuery.first({
            success: function(_hotel) {
                if(_hotel) {                                                                
                        _hotel.set('tempAssignedUser', params.userId);
                        _hotel.add('users', params.userId);
                        _hotel.save(null, {
                            success: function(_hotel) {                                                         
                                params.success(_hotel); 
                            },
                            error: function(_hotel, error) {                                
                                params.error(Response.InternalServerError);
                            }
                        });                                            
                } else {
                    params.error(Response.NotFound);
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                params.error(Response.InternalServerError);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**beforeSave()**

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Hotel', function(req, res) {
    var hotel = req.object;

    //CREATING AND SETTING ACLS TO Hotel
    var hotelACL = new Parse.ACL();   
    **if(hotel.get('tempAssignedUser')) {
        hotelACL.setWriteAccess(hotel.get('tempAssignedUser'), true);
        hotelACL.setReadAccess(hotel.get('tempAssignedUser'), true);    
        hotel.unset('tempAssignedUser');
    }** // If i remove this if condition, my code is working fine                                      
    hotelACL.setRoleWriteAccess('ADMIN', true);
    hotelACL.setRoleReadAccess('ADMIN', true);
    hotelACL.setRoleWriteAccess('SUPER_USER', true);
    hotelACL.setRoleReadAccess('SUPER_USER', true);
    hotelACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    hotel.setACL(hotelACL);
    res.success();
}
```

Comment: Basically it says that you are trying to save `Hotel` object with a pointer to `User` object, which isn't saved. So try save `User` object, and then save `Hotel` object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but user object is already saved and then i am assigning

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that `hotel.get('tempAssignedUser')` returns a valid `objectId` for a user that exists in your User class. Also I am assuming that there is a field called `tempAssignedUser` defined in your `Hotel` class. Now you can try this instead in your `beforeSave`:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Hotel', function(req, res) {
    var hotel = req.object;

    var hotelACL = new Parse.ACL();
    hotelACL.setRoleWriteAccess('ADMIN', true);
    hotelACL.setRoleReadAccess('ADMIN', true);
    hotelACL.setRoleWriteAccess('SUPER_USER', true);
    hotelACL.setRoleReadAccess('SUPER_USER', true);
    hotelACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    if(hotel.get('tempAssignedUser')) {

        // fetch the user object
        Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
        var userObject = new Parse.User();
        userObject.id = hotel.get('tempAssignedUser');

        userObject.fetch().then( function(user) {

            hotelACL.setWriteAccess(user, true);
            hotelACL.setReadAccess(user, true);    
            hotel.unset('tempAssignedUser');
            hotel.setACL(hotelACL);
            res.success();

        }, function(error) {
             response.error(error);
        }); 

    } else {

        hotel.setACL(hotelACL);
        res.success();
    }
});
```

Comment: Still no luck :( The user objectId is valid and a user exists

Comment: Your problem might be due to this line `params.success(_hotel)` Can you stop returning an object in your response.success to test this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting *tempAssignedUser* with a userId.  That is NOT the same thing as setting the *tempAssingedUser* with a **_User** object.  What you are doing is setting a placeholder, which is 'unsaved' regardless of whether the original object with that id is saved or not.

You need to first FETCH the *tempAssignedUser* with id *params.userId* and THEN set the property of **Hotel** with hotel.set("tempAssignedUser",fetchedUser)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried fetching user and set "tempAssignedUser" with fetchedUser but it is not working. It is giving me same error

Comment: Is there another object contained in Hotel?